# Define the Event A Given B?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let ($\Omega , T , P$) be a measured space , P being a probability measure.

Let A,B$\in T$.
A usual question is to calculate P(A|B) (Probability of A Given B);
I want to demonstrate the expression has a sense showing A|B is in T.

What is the definition of the Event A|B ?
In most courses , i can find the expression of the probability of the event, but i can't find anybody giving a definition of the set it defines.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as an event $A|B$. The point is, given $B \in T$, we can define a new probability measure $P_B$ in $T$, defininig $P_B(A)=P(A|B)$.

Note that this probability is "associated" *with the event* $A$. There is no need to define a new "event" $A|B$. The *events* are the same, what changes is the *probability measure*.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. So , to what i understand for now, writing "P(A|B)" is just a abuse of notation ? As P is a probability measure , evaluating A|B by P if A|B has no meaning in term of event is a abuse of notation to me.